# View not updating on value change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3

I have a button in an Ionic Component that I only want to show when audio is playing.

`<button *ngIf="playing">Stop Audio</button>`

I have a service which exposes a public property that is true when audio is playing and false when it isn't.

`public playing = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)`

When I play audio, the button correctly appears, but when the audio stops playing, the button remains unless I click on a different button to change the view state.

I know that the BehaviorSubject is working properly because when I subscribe to it and console log the output, it logs `true` when audio is playing (and the view updates) and `false` when the audio stops (and the view doesn't update).

Comment: Your template code refers to *ngIf="audioService.playing' and the property name in is 'playing'. I am trying to understand the role of audioService here. I am guessing u have this playing variable in the service that u have as a dependency in your component in which case you can't use it directly inside your template without exposing its value to a variable in the component.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I'll edit that. You're correct, `audioPlayingService.playing` is a property of the service that is a dependency in my component. The template references a variable in the component that's updated from a subscription to the service `this.audioPlayingService.playing.subscribe(x => { this.playing = x })`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the async pipe:
`*ngif="audioPlayingService.playing | async"`

Answer (score 0):

So there is two ways you can accomplish this in your component. One is to add a property on the component, and the extract the value into it. So you do something like this:

**Component Class**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  playing: boolean = false;

  constructor(private audioService: AudioService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.audioService.playing.subscribe(playing => this.playing = playing);
  }

}
```

**Component Template**

```
<button *ngIf="playing">Stop Audio</button>
```

Another solution is to use the async pipe, like Ploppy suggested. Then you could do the following:

**Component Class**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  playing: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private audioService: AudioService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.playing = this.audioService.playing;
  }

}
```

**Component template**

```
<button *ngIf="(playing | async)">Stop Audio</button>
```